# Protractor & Cucumberjs after hook doesn't work as expected

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I have written a basic after hook in cucumberjs for some reason , it is not working as expected.It is supposed to attached screenshot and write browser console log , when scenario fails. But it attaches the screen shot after the feature in html report and prints the browser console log at after in between the second scenario[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYOPb.png).Any clue what's wrong??

```
     this.After(function(scenario, callback) {       
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            global.browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(base64png) {
            var decodedImage = new Buffer(base64png,'base64').toString('binary');
            scenario.attach(decodedImage, 'image/png');
       });
        global.browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function (browserlog){         
        browserlog.forEach(function (log) {
          if (log.level.value > 900) {
             console.error(log.message.substring(log.message.indexOf('Error'),log.message.indexOf('\n')))
           }
         })           
        });
        callback();
    } else {
        callback();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the cucumberjs github page https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#attachments

> Images and other binary data can be attached using a stream.Readable. In that case, passing a callback to attach() becomes mandatory:

You could split the single after hook into two separate hooks:

```
this.After(function(scenario, next) {
  browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
    var decodedImage = new Buffer(png, 'base64').toString('binary');
    scenario.attach(decodedImage, 'image/png', next);
  }, function(err) {
    next(err);
  });
});

this.After(function(scenario, next) {
  global.browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function (browserlog){
    browserlog.forEach(function (log) {
      if (log.level.value > 900) {
        console.error(log.message.substring(log.message.indexOf('Error'),log.message.indexOf('\n')))
      }
    });
  });
});
```